# Solving a Hamilton-Jacobi equation with discontinuous data

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm supposed to solve the equation
$$\partial_tu+|\partial_xu|=0$$
for $u:\mathbb R\times(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ subject to the initial condition
$$u(x,0)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0,&x\leq0\\1,&x>0.\end{array}\right.$$
I tried the method of characteristics and found that a solution must be constant on characteristics so there must be some curve that splits the $t\times x$ plane into a left region where $u=0$ and a right region where $u=0$. I thought that could derive what the curve must be in the manner of the Rankine-Hugoniot shock condition in order for $u$ to be a weak solution (since it seems there can't be a strong solution), but because of the nonlinearity I could not see how to even define what a weak solution would be (it is not in the form $F(u)_x$.

The other thing I tried is a viscosity solution to $\partial_tu-\epsilon\partial_x^2u+|\partial_xu|=0$ but upon taking $\epsilon\to0$ I arrived at a solution with a jump. The question just says to "solve" the equation which makes me think there should be a unique classical solution which I'm missing.

Comment: Is the second condition actually $x>0$?

Comment: @Ian yes it is sorry

Comment: With the initial conditions, I think the absolute value plays no role in the solution. Solve it without it and try...

Comment: @RafaBudría This would give two of the infinitely many piecewise constant "solutions".

Comment: Use the Hopf-Lax Formula.

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the suggestion. Since $H=|p|$ I get $v=sgn(p)$ and $L(v)=vp-H(p)=0$ which would make the Hopf-Lax formula uninteresting. Did I make an error?